# Non existent files downloaded

Tags: orangedox

Orangedox is showing new downloads of a file that has been deleted from Dropbox.

I don't understand how this occurs.
Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

If the file was deleted from Dropbox but the link on Orangedox wasn't (and is still active) users will still be able to access the link, and consequently will see the "download" landing page.  For file type other than folders and PDF's Orangedox will consider clicking on the "download" button within the landing page as a "download" even if the Dropbox file was removed.  Hence why you still see people trying to access your deleted Dropbox file.

Comment: FYI this behaviour will be changing in future releases of Orangedox .. will update this post when this happens